# Visual Studio 2013 GitHub

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013

I sync sources to GitHub using Visual Studio 2013 with a particular account, but the following error when trying to come up with another account occurs.

An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error). Response status code does not Indicate success: 403 Forbidden).

Please someone you idea what it is?

Answer (score 14):

You should use a HTTP debbuging proxy server (i.e. fiddler), and try to synchronize your commit with Visual Studio (Visual Studio Tools for Git extension). In my case I realized that I was logged with another git account and VS tries to login with that account (Request: Permission to repo/repo.git denied to UserX).

So I run 'rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr' and erase my credentials (maybe only update could works). When I tried to sync again, VS ask for credentials and everything works fine.

Comment: @Natrium what is fiddler log when you try to synchronize?

Comment: @UUHHIVS thanks for your reply. I was doing it wrong. I had to fork first

Answer (score 0):

Check on your local project path the config file allocated in .git folder. It should be something like this:

```
[core]
   bare = false
   repositoryformatversion = 0
   filemode = false
   symlinks = false
   ignorecase = true
   logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
   url = https://github.com/aGitHubUser/aRepo.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
   remote = origin
   merge = refs/heads/master
```

Equally, **be sure**, that you have permissions on the reopsitory on GitHub web.

I hope that it helps you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I receive this error typically in a team environment when my team leads 'forgot' to give me rights to the GitHub repos.

Answer (score 0):

My one cent:

Add your second account as a collaborator to the repository. To add a collaborator, go to repository settings page -> collaborators.

Answer (score 0):

I started facing this issue when I changed my bitbucket password.

So I deleted the Source tree default authentication.
When I tried to sync again, it asked for credentials.   After providing new credentials everything started working again.