# Visual studio 2013 github sync error 403

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013, synchronization

I'm getting an error 403:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).

when trying to push or sync Unsynced Commits using visual studio team explorer.

When using the command line or sourcetree for example, everything is working fine. did anyone had this error before and find a way how to fix it?

I'm not using ssh.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer here. Deleted the github account from the list and next Vs asking for credentials...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401455/1319157

Answer (score 0):

**TFS 2013 Git push VS 2017 Forbidden error-403**

[unable to access. requested url returned error: 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEvFv.jpg)

I got this error while trying to push my local git repository to on-prem TFS 2013 server. I got same error from VS 2017 and command line.

After spending lot of time on playing around with global config settings, I figured out that the

> issue is caused by internal proxy server.

Cleared git credentials from Windows Credentials Manager (as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401455/1319157).

But problem still did not go away. So I added NO_PROXY to environment variables as mentioned in ([Only use a proxy for certain git urls/domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067534/only-use-a-proxy-for-certain-git-urls-domains/16069911#16069911))

```
NO_PROXY  
my_internal_tfs,localhost,127.0.0.1
```

This worked like a charm. make sure to close and re-open Visual studio or command prompt after changing environment variables.

Below are some useful links I found about git credential manager. Hope this may be helpful for someone.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage
https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows
https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/master/Docs/Faq.md#q-i-thought-microsoft-was-maintaining-this-why-does-the-gcm-not-work-as-expected-with-tfs