# Git not working on VS Professional 2012

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have integrated the Git source control on my VS Professional 2012 with Update 5, the installation works fine without error. I just followed the instruction provided by Microsoft [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.VisualStudioToolsforGit).

When I try to clone a repoitory I got this error

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
Response status code does not indicate success: 301 (Moved Permanently).
```

I already tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516048/visual-studio-2013-github/29401455)

And also clearing the credentials of my git stored in my pc, but it didn't work,

And I manually clone it with command line and its work.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the URL for the repository is correct? Can you access it using command line git?

Comment: Yes, the url is correct. I manually clone it using cli.

Comment: Could it be that git itself handles the move, but libgit2 doesn't? Doesn't 301 status code come with the redirect url as part of the response?